# JS var to get PHP value in WP

Tags: php, javascript, var

I was reading all similar questions and answers around, but none seem to work for me.

i have this:

```
<script>
var MyCity  = "<?php echo 'Cityville';?>";
</script>
```

but this outputs the entire php. I also tried this:

```
<?php echo json_encode('City'); ?>
```

all these in a WP widget.

any ideas?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have quotes around your echo statement, you need to have them around your variable AFTER it has been output to function within the script, like so:

```
<script>
    var MyCity  = <?php echo '"Cityville"';?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
<script>
var MyCity  = <?php echo 'Cityville';?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Almost there, however the string would still need quotes once it has been output by the php for the JS to pick it up as a string.

Comment: look at this jsfiddle, it doesnt work properly: check this out: jsfiddle.net/kRRWH

Answer (score 1):

I think you should encode with json_encode, it will handle single quote or double quote in string.

```
<?php $city = 'Cityville'; ?>
<script>
  var MyCity = <?php echo json_encode($city); ?>;
</script>
```